# NestJS Exception filter messes up error array if it comes from ValidationPipe

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, httpexception

So I use the ValidationPipe to validate my DTOs in NestJS, like this:

```js
// auth.dto.ts
export class AuthDto {
  @IsEmail()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  email: string;
}
```

Without the Exception filter the error message works as intended. I leave the email field empty and I receive an array of error messages:

```json
// Response - Message array, but no wrapper
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "message": [
    "email should not be empty",
    "email must be an email"
  ],
  "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

Perfect. Now I want to implement a wrapper for the error messages, so I create a new filter and add it to to bootstrap:

```js
// main.ts
async function bootstrap() {
  // ...
  app.useGlobalFilters(new GlobalExceptionFilter());
}
bootstrap();
```

```js
// global-exception.filter.ts
import {
  ArgumentsHost,
  Catch,
  ExceptionFilter,
  HttpException,
  HttpStatus,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Response } from 'express';
import { IncomingMessage } from 'http';

export const getStatusCode = <T>(exception: T): number => {
  return exception instanceof HttpException
    ? exception.getStatus()
    : HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
};

export const getErrorMessage = <T>(exception: T): string => {
  return exception instanceof HttpException
    ? exception.message
    : String(exception);
};

@Catch()
export class GlobalExceptionFilter<T> implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: T, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
    const request = ctx.getRequest<IncomingMessage>();
    const statusCode = getStatusCode<T>(exception);
    const message = getErrorMessage<T>(exception);

    response.status(statusCode).json({
      error: {
        timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
        path: request.url,
        statusCode,
        message,
      },
    });
  }
}
```

It works great for most of my errors:

```json
// Response - Good format (wrapped), single message expected
{
  "error": {
    "timestamp": "2022-05-11T19:54:59.093Z",
    "path": "/auth/signup",
    "statusCode": 400,
    "message": "Email already in use"
  }
}
```

But when I get a ValidationError from the ValidationPipe it should give me an array or messages like before, but it gives this message instead:

```json
// Response - Wrapper: check, single message instead of array
{
  "error": {
    "timestamp": "2022-05-11T19:59:17.282Z",
    "path": "/auth/signup",
    "statusCode": 400,
    "message": "Bad Request Exception" // it should be "message": ["not empty", "must be email"]
  }
}
```

The exception object in my exception filter has a response field which contains the message array:

```js
// HttpException object inside the filter class
{
  response: {
    statusCode: 400,
    message: [ 'email should not be empty', 'email must be an email' ],
    error: 'Bad Request'
  },
  status: 400
}
```

But `exception.response.message` doesn't work, because the field is private and TypeScript throws an error:
`Property 'response' is private and only accessible within class 'HttpException'.`

Does any of you know how could I reach the message array, so I could format my error response properly?

EDIT: Sorry for the long post!

Comment: Try `exception["response"]["message"]`. This bypasses the `private` restriction

Comment: Great tip! It works!

Comment: @TobiasS. : This works fine with the solution you provided but any idea how we can make it work in case of using I18nValidationPipe() since I need to provide internationalization?

I am using something like this : 
@UsePipes(new I18nValidationPipe({ whitelist: true, transform: true }))

And doing this in the GlobalExceptionFilter class we are getting only 
exception. response

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [@tobias-s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8613630/tobias-s) commented, there's a workaround, which solved the problem:

> Try exception["response"]["message"]. This bypasses the private restriction

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `@Catch` decorator, you could get a `HttpException` or not, so we need to evaluate it.

Let's create an interface to "parse" Nest.js built-in `HttpException` class response:

```
export interface HttpExceptionResponse {
    statusCode: number;
    message: any;
    error: string;
}
```

Now we can process it:

```
export const getErrorMessage = <T>(exception: T): any => {

  if(exception instanceof HttpException) {

    const errorResponse = exception.getResponse();
    const errorMessage = (errorResponse as HttpExceptionResponse).message || exception.message;

    return errorMessage;
  } else {
    return String(exception);
  }
};
```

`exception.getResponse()` can be a string or an object, that's because we handle it as `message: any` of course.